# Mongoose: Creating a 'virtual column' of values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

This is somewhat vague question, but please, bear with me:)

example schema:

```
var scoreSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
    name : String,
    scores : String
});
```

Example row: name: John, scores: "2, 4, 6, 1, 7"

for every row, i need to convert the scores string into array and sort. `scores.split(",").sort();`
 Only this resulting array will ever be used, but i'd still need to keep the original long string in the database.

So I need to create some sort of 'virtual' column or reference which can be easily accessed later. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mongoose's [virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals) support for this:

```
scoreSchema.virtual('splitScores').get(function() {
    return this.scores.split(",").sort();
});
```

With that in place, any score document instance will have a `splitScores` property that's the sorted array version of `scores`.